# PyQt5 : How to send a resize event from QMdiArea to Subwindows?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

My apologies if his is too obvious, but I could not find an example for it. I am trying to pass down a resizeEvent from a QMdiArea window to its Subwindows.

```
def main():
    global mdiArea
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    mdiArea = StQMdiArea()
    cw = ControlWindow()

    mdiArea.addSubWindow(cw)
    mdiArea.setWindowTitle('My Prog')
    mdiArea.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When I get a resize event in QMdiArea, I want to pass it on to the SubWindows:

```
def resizeEvent(self, event):
    subWinList = QMdiArea.subWindowList(self)
    g = self.geometry()
    for sw in subWinList:
        #--> Here where I like to send the resize event to all sw
    return super(StQMdiArea, self).resizeEvent(event)
```

Is there a method to propagate the event to subwindows? I thought this would be simple, but I was not able to find a method for it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by "propagate"? You can of course simply emit a custom signal from the `resizeEvent`. Or just call a subwindow method directly. What exactly is wrong with the code you already have? What *specifically* are you trying to achieve?

Comment: AFAICS, all you need to do is call `super(StQMdiArea, self).resizeEvent(event)` **first** (there's no need to return from it), and then call `sw.setGeometry(g)` in the loop afterwards.

Comment: "propagate" I meant to trigger resize event in all the subwindows. The code above does not trigger it. Each subwindow is supposed  to resize itself when it gets the event. I just want to trigger it when the MdiArea is resized

Comment: I tried sw.setGeometry(g) and that triggers it.  This helps, but not what I want. I want for each subwindow to re-scale itself bases on its current size and the new parent size so it can maintain proportionality.

Comment: So what's stopping you doing that? Just set the geometry in whatever way you like using the method I suggested.